# File Download in Chrome appears incorrect file name [PageName].aspx. It worked before I updated my Chrome

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, iis-7

This is a asp.net 3.5 website.

Files can be download correctly in IE/FF. But not chrome.

The file is downloaded as "ASPS_Page_Name.aspx".

However it worked before I updated my chrome browser to 20.0.1132.47 m.

I have this function to filter out MIME types (intended for ff, the previous chrome doesn't need this function)

```
Private Shared Function GetContentType(ByVal fileType As String) As String

    Select Case fileType

        'set to "application/vnd.ms-excel" MIME type for firefox
        'MIME Types for IIS
        Case "xls"
            Return "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        Case "xlsx"
            Return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

        Case "pdf"
            Return "application/pdf"

        Case "doc"
            Return "application/msword"

        Case "docx"
            Return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

        Case "ppt"
            Return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"

        Case "pptx"
            Return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"

        Case Else
            Return "application/octet-stream"

    End Select

End Function
```

At this moment, with this function xls/xlsx/pdf/.. files can be downloaded with correct name, I'm wondering whether I need to specify the all mime types here or in web.config to make the download work.

Does anyone know what happened to chrome and how to fix this "bug"?

This is the download function, should be ok caz it works before.

```
Public Shared Sub StreamFileToClient(ByVal memoryStream As IO.MemoryStream, ByVal fileName As String, ByVal fileType As String)

    Try

        memoryStream.Position = 0

        'Serve to client
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;attachment; filename=" & fileName & "." & fileType)
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", memoryStream.Length.ToString())
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileType)

        'octet-stream";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray)
        'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        'well good to use completerequest rather than .end nand .close. Read MSDN.
        'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
        'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()


    Catch ex As Exception


    Finally
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()


        memoryStream.Flush()
        memoryStream.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some guidance in [bug 103618](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103618), which documents that Chrome has become more strict in it's parsing of attachment=*, whereby if the name includes any of the delimiters then the name will not be what you expect.

Also, "inline" doesn't appear to be a part of the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) so we might be ignoring that (although that is what IE has to use).  Also you have "inline" and "attachment", remove inline and test with Chrome.

Comment: really really decent answer! It fixed issue in Chrome. IE7~9 works fine without "inline". thx.