# Downloading simple text/csv file in Chrome fails

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, google-chrome, webforms

I'm trying to figure out a problem that we're facing with the download and the problem seems to exist only in Chrome and only for txt and csv files. Downloading zip files works just as expected. IE and Firefox works for all scenarios.
For some reason Chrome downloads both txt and csv files without properly setting the name. Files inherit the name of the page which they were downloaded from, and don't have an extension ([image: see screenshot]).

I have a simple Webform with just 3 linkbuttons a fairly straightforward code behind, which I simplified for the sake of this question.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Private Const FILE_PATH_CSV As String = "D:\Temp\Download\testFile.csv"
    Private Const FILE_PATH_ZIP As String = "D:\Temp\Download\testFile.zip"
    Private Const FILE_PATH_TXT As String = "D:\Temp\Download\testFile.txt"

    Private Sub btnDownloadCSV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownloadCSV.Click
        Dim file As New FileInfo(FILE_PATH_CSV)
        If Not file.Exists() Then
            Throw New Exception("No file")
        End If
        Try
            DownloadFile(file)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'TODO: Log!
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDownloadTXT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownloadTXT.Click
        Dim file As New FileInfo(FILE_PATH_TXT)
        If Not file.Exists() Then
            Throw New Exception("No file")
        End If
        Try
            DownloadFile(file)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'TODO: Log!
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDownloadZIP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownloadZIP.Click
        Dim file As New FileInfo(FILE_PATH_ZIP)
        If Not file.Exists() Then
            Throw New Exception("No file")
        End If
        Try
            DownloadFile(file)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'TODO: Log!
        Finally
            With Response
                .Flush()
                .End()
            End With
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DownloadFile(ByVal file As FileInfo)
        With Response
            .Clear()
            .ClearHeaders()
            .ClearContent()
            .Buffer = True

            Response.ContentType = GetContentType(file)
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", String.Format("attachment;filename=""{0}""", file.Name.ToString()))
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString())
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName)
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Function GetContentType(ByVal file As FileInfo)
        Select Case file.Extension.ToLower()
            Case ".txt", ".csv"
                Return "application/octet-stream"
            Case ".zip"
                Return "application/x-zip-compressed"
            Case Else
                Return "application/octet-stream"
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

I've tried switching the content type to 'text/plain' or other options as I searched the web for the answer but had no luck. I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't find anything that answers my question online.
Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I guess I should be more careful with copy/paste as that caused me 2 days of very frustrated debugging.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", String.Format("attachment;filename=""{0}""", file.Name.ToString()))
```

Should be

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=""{0}""", file.Name.ToString()))
```

Extra colon in there was not necessary and when I removed it - everything worked! 
Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your MIME types to the [correct values](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text).

```
        Case ".csv"
            Return "text/csv"
        Case ".txt"
            Return "text/plain"
```

You may also need to change the method of sending the file from

```
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName)
```

to

```
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName, False)
```

The documentation on MSDN isn't clear about what the differences are between the two methods. I have never used `TransmitFile`, but have used `WriteFile` successfully.

Comment: I've tried that even before posting and it makes no difference for Chrome.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I didn't know about the WriteFile option, but that doesn't seem to work either. 

After changing to the Response.WriteFile(filename, False) the results are as follows:

CSV - downloaded with the "Default" name

Zip - Downloaded just fine with the correct name and extensions

Txt displays the following: http://i.imgur.com/h8PVJPO.png

Comment: You can try using `application/csv` or `application/text` for the MIME types, but that isn't part of the standard. It may give you the filename you want, but I don't expect it to work.

Comment: That's actually one of the things I tried as well, before posting, but  it didn't work and I didn't see it on the list of accepted values. 
I'm wondering if this is a bug, that pertains to Chrome as everything works fine in IE and FF? 
I noticed something similar to that in my searches (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432538/file-download-in-chrome-appears-incorrect-file-name-pagename-aspx-it-worked-b?rq=1). It's not exactly what I'm up against but close enough. Don't you think?

Comment: It would seem so. There was a mention of a ["bug" in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103618) that talks about being more strict in the interpretation of the [standard - Section 14](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: FTR, from [ASP.NET Response.TransmitFile File Locking](http://www.hashemian.com/blog/2008/11/asp-net-response-transmitfile-file-locking.htm): "TransmitFile in ASP.NET makes use of the Windows TransmitFile API function which directly streams a file to an open socket. It is more optimized than WriteFile which buffers the entire content of the file before emitting it."

Comment: From the same article: "While TransmitFile API function is optimized, care must be taken to avoid having the streamed data getting mixed with other data and my hunch is that some locking mechanism is used to assure an orderly and sequential transmission of data under ASP.NET. That's all fine until one needs to write to the file which could get shot down while the lock is still active." The issue above is specifically related to file locking. Changing the file opening method for the stream will correct the issue.